# How can I sort list of pairs using second key in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of nested lists:

```
e = [['Tina', 37.2], ['Harsh', 39], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Akriti', 41]]
```

How do you sort by numerical value, yet the names 'follow' the 'grade'?
I could use dict, but I think it misses the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the list with a custom key:

```
result = sorted(e, key = lambda x : x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example Harry and Berry have the same value.

If you want ties to be sorted by name, a variation of the answers you got already would be something like this:

```
e = [['Tina', 37.2], ['Harsh', 39], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Akriti', 41]]

e.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1], x[0]))

print(e)
#[['Tina', 37.2], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]
```

Comment: Why not just the much simpler `lambda x: (x[1], x[0])`?

Comment: Only because I didn't think about it :)  Will edit. Thanks.