# How would I append a list with a variable(decimals) and a word to then print a list sorted from greatest to least based on the variable with the word

Tags: python

So I have a set of numbers(decimals) with a corresponding word. I need then to append that list with the number and the corresponding word. Next I need to sort and print the numbers with the corresponding word based on the variable.

It should print out like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yvZy.png)

```
NUM  WORD
3.5 d
3.2 c
2.1 a
0.5 b
```

Comment: This is a rather overbroad question that amounts to "write my code for me" without being clear on input format (so even if people wanted to answer, they couldn't). There are a ton of questions already asked on sorting paired data by one element or the other (e.g. [How can I sort list of pairs using second key in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56094640/364696)); have you tried to use them as a base for your own solution?

Comment: The task you've described is very easy.  Create a list of tuples containing `(0.5,'b'), (3.2,'c'), (3.5,'d'), (2.1,'a')`, and sort it in reverse order.  Problem solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
data=((0.5,'b'), (3.2,'c'), (3.5,'d'), (2.1,'a'))
lst=[]
for x in data:
    lst.append(x[0])
lst.sort(reverse=True)
for y in lst:
    for x in data:
        if y==x[0]:
            print(x)
```